# Bulk Insert not working in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server-2008, csv, bulkinsert

Here's my SQL to bulk load a CSV file into SQL Server 2008, but its returning:

```
0 row(s) affected.
```

Code:

```
USE energyDB
GO

BULK INSERT energydata
FROM 'c:\temp\24544_MSSQL_out.csv'
WITH
(
  FIRSTROW = 2,
  FIELDTERMINATOR = ',',
  ROWTERMINATOR = '\n'
)
GO
```

The CSV file looks like this (the top line is ignored)

```
24544,"1970-01-01 10:00:00","8056060 kWh"
24544,"2012-12-04 00:15:00",0.176
24544,"2012-12-04 00:30:00",0.163
24544,"2012-12-04 00:45:00",0.016
```

Comment: And what is the table structure of `EnergyData` that you're inserting into?

Answer (score 0):

Bulk insert doesn't remove quotes from the data, you'll either need to change the file being imported or import to a table where every column is a character field and strip the quotes and convert datatypes in a query. I've just found the following MSDN article:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188609.aspx

It states:

Comma-separated value (CSV) files are not supported by SQL Server bulk-import operations.

And then continues on with a few examples of the situations it will work under.

Answer (score 0):

This question is a little old, but it showed up when I searched for the problem, so I thought I would provide my solution.

In my case it was a simple mistake of not inserting into the right table, so be sure to check the table that you are inserting into. In trying to figure out what was going on though, I found that you can have the bulk insert process create an error file that will hopefully guide you in the right direction. To do this, you can use something like `ERRORFILE ='E:\Error.txt'`. This should output the error you are receiving to a file called Error.txt. I've provided a full example below:

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION
BEGIN TRY
BULK INSERT [Table Name]
FROM 'E:\FileName.csv'
WITH (FIELDTERMINATOR = ',', ROWTERMINATOR = '\n', ERRORFILE ='E:\Error.txt')
COMMIT TRANSACTION
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
END CATCH
```

You'll notice that I've wrapped the bulk insert process in a Transaction. This is so that if any issue occurs during the bulk insert it will rollback everything and I won't get a partial data import.